# How to align ul to the center in Skeleton?

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Very new to front-end. I'm designing my site with the Skeleton Responsive Framework and I'm having trouble getting my footer nav to center in the mobile layout. It currently aligns to the left.

I assume I'm targetting something incorrectly. Can anyone help?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div class="band bottom">
     <footer class="container last">
         <hr>       
            <div class="sixteen footer-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                </ul>           
            </div>

            <div class="eight columns credit">
               <p>&copy; 2013 Jacob Taylor</p>
            </div>

     </footer> <! --- End Container --->
</div>  <! --- End Band --->
```

And here is the CSS for both the desktop and mobile versions respecitvely:

```
/* Footer */

.bottom footer {
    font-size: 12px;
}

div.footer-nav ul,
div.footer-nav ul li {
    margin: 0px;
}

div.footer-nav ul li {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

div.footer-nav ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0px 21px 21px 0px;
    color: #2f3239; 
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.footer-nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #2f3239;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;

}

div.credit {
    text-align: right;
}

/* Footer */    

footer.last,
div.credit,
div.footer-nav {
    text-align: center;
}

div.footer-nav ul {
    text-align:center;  
}
```

Comment: Your `<footer class="container last">` is taking 100% width. Reduce it and center align your `<div class="band bottom" align="center">`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .sixteen class from .footer-nav and set it to something less than 100% i.e. ten perhaps and add margin: 0 auto to .footer-nav

Comment: Made these changes as suggested. Didn't seem to make a difference.
Is there anything in Skeleton that I might need to reset?

It only seems to be the ul being effect. The p in .credit is centering fine.

Comment: Please check if the Ul has a float:left and a padding assigned to it if so please overwrite that to float:none; padding:0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it looks like you are trying to use a 16 column object for the list. Reduce the number of columns to something less than twelve columns. And make sure you are using the class "columns" to get the grid working.

```
<div class="band bottom">
 <footer class="container last footer">
        <hr>
        <div class="twelve columns footer__links">
            <ul class="nav--footer">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>
        <div class="four columns">
            <div class="credit">&copy; 2013 Jacob Taylor</div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

On another note, Your css seems very verbose and obfuscated. Take a look at a refactored version of your css and markup. Ideally we want to avoid any extra descendant selectors and calling out unqualified element e.g "div.class_name" when writing a rule.

```
.footer {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.footer__links {
    text-align: center;
}
.nav--footer{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.nav--footer li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right: 4em;
}
.nav--footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2f3239; 
}
.nav--footer a:hover {
    color: #2f3239;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;

}
.credit {
    text-align: right;
}
```